# Какой функцией получить размер окна по его хэндлу?

Tags: winapi

Какой функцией получить размер окна по его хэндлу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) или [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
RECT rect = {0};

GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Справедливости ради надо сказать, что `GetWindowRect` возвращает неверные значения для окон верхнего уровня при включенном Aero.

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI * DwmIsCompositionEnabled_Func)(BOOL*);

RECT MaximizedWindowFix(HWND handle, RECT windowRect)
{
    RECT res = windowRect;
    if (IsWindowMaximized(handle))
    {
        RECT screenRect = ScreenFromRectangle(windowRect);
        if (windowRect.left < screenRect.left)
        {
            windowRect.right -= (screenRect.left - windowRect.left) /** 2*/;
            windowRect.left = screenRect.left;
        }
        if (windowRect.top < screenRect.top)
        {
            windowRect.bottom -= (screenRect.top - windowRect.top) /** 2*/;
            windowRect.top = screenRect.top;
        }
        IntersectRect(&res, &windowRect, &screenRect);
        //  windowRect.Intersect(screenRect);
    }
    return res;
}
BOOL MyGetWindowRect(HWND hWnd, RECT* res, bool MaximizedFix = true)
{
    if (!WinUtils::IsVista())
    {
        return GetWindowRect(hWnd, res);
    }
    static HMODULE DllModule =  LoadLibrary(_T("dwmapi.dll"));
    if (DllModule)
    {
        DwmIsCompositionEnabled_Func IsCompEnabledFunc = reinterpret_cast<DwmIsCompositionEnabled_Func>( GetProcAddress(
              DllModule, "DwmIsCompositionEnabled"));
        if (IsCompEnabledFunc)
        {
            BOOL isEnabled = false;
            if (S_OK == IsCompEnabledFunc( &isEnabled))
                if (isEnabled)
                {
                    DwmGetWindowAttribute_Func Func = reinterpret_cast<DwmGetWindowAttribute_Func>(GetProcAddress(DllModule, "DwmGetWindowAttribute"));
                    if (Func)
                    {
                        if (S_OK == Func( hWnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, res, sizeof(RECT)))
                        {
                            if (MaximizedFix)
                                *res = MaximizedWindowFix(hWnd, *res);
                            return TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return GetWindowRect(hWnd, res);
}
```